# Swift - ¿Cuándo usar un Array y cuándo un Set?

Tags: array, swift, set

He estado revisando la documentación de Swift 5 y me ha surgido la duda de cuándo sería recomendable usar un Array y cuándo un Set.

¿Qué ventajas e inconvenientes tendría cada uno?.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambos funcionan de forma muy parecida.

- Un array se utiliza como una lista de ítems con un orden determinado.
- El set es un conjunto de elementos que no tiene un orden determinado
  y cada elemento solo puede aparecer una vez dentro del set.

En general es más rápido localizar un elemento dentro de un set que en un array, esto se nota especialmente cuando tenemos muchos elementos dentro de la lista.

Usa **Array**:

- El orden de los elementos es importante
- Los elementos se pueden repetir
- El rendimiento al buscar no es importante

Usa **Set**:

- El orden de los elementos no importa
- Los elementos son únicos dentro de la lista
- El rendimiento en las búsquedas es importante

Comment: Muchas gracias, me queda claro.